# How can I implement a rest web service containing a Neo4 graph data base?

Tags: rest, neo4j, xamarin.android

Is it possible to develop a REST web service with Neo4J graph data base ? Well I have an application for indoor navigation and I need to create my data base of graphs to be able to calculates then paths between the nodes.

So I thought maybe it will be usefull to begin with Neo4J. And I know that Xamarin can take informations from the REST web service using HTTP request (GET POST DELETE PUT).

So I am really beginner in this domain and I need first boost to start. Can you tell me please how I can create my REST web service with Neo4J to be hosted then in a VPS and used by my Xamarin.Android application?

Comment: Could you please be much more specific?

Comment: There are many ways to build a RESTful API, and implementation can be done in *many* ways, via many different languages, frameworks, etc. You'd just need to translate app-specific API calls to the database of choice (in this case, Neo4j). This is a super-broad question (which will likely get you a lot of opinions). Even knowing you'll be connecting with Xamarin doesn't narrow down the scope, since API's are going to be independent of the client you use (unless you're using something very specific to the client framework's implementation). I see this as off-topic for StackOverflow.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. (sorry the question has so little context that I had to adopt my answer to this.)

After question has been refined here a more complete answer.

Neo4j by itself is a extensible engine to serve rest requests. Take a look at the existing REST API, see http://neo4j.com/docs/rest-docs/current/ and http://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/3.0/http-api/#http-api-transactional

The existing REST API is extensible by [unamanged extensions](http://neo4j.com/docs/java-reference/current/#server-unmanaged-extensions). This allows you to implement your own business logic.

Comment: Thank you. I have edited my question. I would appreciate more if you adopt your answer to my edited question.